# Slickgrid: Open bootstrap modal when clicked on the row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slickgrid

I am using Slickgrid in my webpage to display data and this works fine (used examples from [here](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)). One of the example shows how to display the active cell's row data in a modal form to run CRUD operations.

However, what I want to do is to open a bootstrap modal display the row data but not sure how to do this.

Have tried searching for suggestions, but couldn't find one. Are there any resources or tutorials available, which talks about this?

Thanks,
Navin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to run bootstrap modals init after loading slickgrid data

```
loader.onDataLoaded.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    $(".modal").modal() 
 });
```